# How to get ClassLoader of newly created JPMS layer?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

Maybe it is simple question but still can find how to do it. Let's suppose I use the following code to create layer

```
ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(moduleCPath);
ModuleLayer parent = ModuleLayer.boot();
Configuration cf = parent.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of("module-c"));
ClassLoader scl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ModuleLayer myLayer = parent.defineModulesWithOneLoader(cf, scl);
```

As I understand for `myLayer` one classloader was created. How can I get reference to this classloader having reference to `myLayer` and without knowing what classes can be inside `myLayer` modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `ModuleLayer` is created each `Module` gets mapped to a `ClassLoader`.

> #### `ModuleLayer`
>
> A layer is created from a graph of modules in a Configuration and a function that **maps each module to a ClassLoader**.

A `ModuleLayer` has no concept of a `ClassLoader` because there is no guarantee that every `Module` will have the same `ClassLoader`. Instead, the `ClassLoader` is associated with each individual `Module`, which you can get via [`Module.getClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getClassLoader()).

Since you are using [`ModuleLayer.defineModulesWithOneLoader(Configuration,ClassLoader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#defineModulesWithOneLoader(java.lang.module.Configuration,java.lang.ClassLoader))<sup>1</sup>, however, there *is* a guarantee that each `Module` will have the same `ClassLoader`. This means you can get the `ClassLoader` from any `Module` in the `ModuleLayer` and consider it as the "`ClassLoader` of the `ModuleLayer`".

```
ModuleLayer layer = parent.defineModulesWithOneLoader(...);
ClassLoader loader = layer.modules().iterator().next().getClassLoader();
```

Note that this won't work as intended if:

- The `ModuleLayer` is empty (has no `Module`s).

  - `iterator().next()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.
- You create the `ModuleLayer` via [`defineModulesWithManyLoaders(Configuration,ClassLoader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#defineModulesWithManyLoaders(java.lang.module.Configuration,java.lang.ClassLoader))<sup>1</sup>

  - Every `Module` will have its own `ClassLoader`.
- You create the `ModuleLayer` via [`defineModules(Configuration,Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#defineModules(java.lang.module.Configuration,java.util.function.Function)) and the `Function` doesn't return the same `ClassLoader` every time.

  - Allows any combination of `Module` to `ClassLoader`. Also, each `ClassLoader` can potentially have different parents. This method provides the most flexibility when defining `ModuleLayer`s.

---

<sup>1. The methods `defineModulesWithOneLoader` and `defineModulesWithManyLoaders` are, in effect, convenience methods for `defineModules` for two pre-definable use cases; each `Module` has the same `ClassLoader` and each `Module` has their own `ClassLoader`, respectively.</sup>